# Azure Data Factory Portal Blades Status Cache Reset

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory, azureportal

I have a fairly complex Azure Data Factory (ADF) with many datasets covering a variety of time slices intervals etc. Some of these datasets throw errors from time to time and need to be fixed. Typically I'll deal with the error behind the scenes, in other Azure services or offline. Then once its resolved I simply set the errored/failed time slice status manually using PowerShell.

For example:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactorySliceStatus `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    -DataFactoryName $ADFName.DataFactoryName `
    -DatasetName $Dataset.DatasetName `
    -StartDateTime 2017-02-23 `
    -EndDateTime 2017-02-24 `
    -Status "Waiting" `
    -UpdateType "Individual"
```

However, in doing this the portal does not react very well when it comes to reporting the actual errors at the main ADF blade. Snippet below.

[image]

In the case of the above I certainly do not have 21 errored datasets! How dare it! :-)

So, my question is. Do we know of a way to clear the cache or reset these values in the ADF portal blades? They are inaccurate and it doesn't look great if the customer decides to check on things.

Ideally I'd scrap the portal UI altogether! PowerShell for the win :-)

Many thanks for your time and support.